# display array information in laravel 5 view

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel. I am trying send an array to my view but I am getting the following exception

ErrorException in LandingPagesController.php line 26:
Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data'

My controller is looking like this

```
public function index($param)
{
    $data = LandingPage::where('LandingPage','=',$param)->first();
    var_dump($data->landingpage);

    return view('lp', compact(data));
}
```

my view looks like

```
@if ( $data )
    no data
@else
    do stuff...
@endif
```

the var_dump is printing in the screen string 'tests' (length=5)
so I know that data has something otherwise will not print, so i dont understand what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
 return view('lp', compact('data'));
```

Comment: I think you just missed that one. :)